# How to make a WPF DataGrid with alternating row colors, and a fix color section (ignoring alternation)

Tags: wpf, xaml, user-interface

I have a datagrid that I'm trying to make resemble:
[image]

I'm using the `AlternatingRowBackground` attribute to perform the alternating colors.  For the fixed color section, I have XAML that resembles:

```
            <DataGrid.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=ShouldBeFixedColor}" Value="True">
                            <DataTrigger.Setters>
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue" />
                            </DataTrigger.Setters>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.Resources>
```

The problem with this approach is that the "alternating color" takes precedence over the fixed color style trigger.  So, at the bottom instead of blue-blue-blue it is blue-gray-blue.

Any ideas on how to archive the desired coloring?  I'd rather do this all at the XAML level if possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Made some changes based upon other SO answers.  Hopefully this helps someone in the future.

1. Yank `AlternatingRowBackground=...` from the grid.  Add `AlternationCount="2"`
2. Add the block below to do the styling (manually doing the alternating rows)

   ```
           <DataGrid.RowStyle>
               <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                   <Style.Triggers>
                       <Trigger Property="AlternationIndex" Value="0">
                           <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
                       </Trigger>
                       <Trigger Property="AlternationIndex" Value="1">
                           <Setter Property="Background" Value="WhiteSmoke" />
                       </Trigger>
                       <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Selectable}" Value="False">
                           <DataTrigger.Setters>
                               <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray" />
                           </DataTrigger.Setters>
                       </DataTrigger>
                   </Style.Triggers>
               </Style>
           </DataGrid.RowStyle>
   ```

Comment: Nice, clean answer! Just to add some further detail: the order of the Triggers is important here. If you moved the DataTrigger to the top then it would fire first but then be subsequently overwritten by one of the AlernationIndex triggers.

Comment: Thanks. Saved me a whole lot of time.

Comment: @Andy amazing that I wrote this over 9 years ago and it's still helpful.  I've forgotten all of my limited WPF since.  Glad to have helped

Answer (score 0):

In case someone else is also looking for the same thing done in code:

```
Style rowStyle = new Style(typeof(DataGridRow));

Trigger rowTrigger = new Trigger();
rowTrigger.Property = DataGridRow.AlternationIndexProperty;
rowTrigger.Value = 0;

Setter rowSetter = new Setter(DataGridRow.BackgroundProperty, Brushes.Yellow);
rowTrigger.Setters.Add(rowSetter);

Trigger alternateRowTrigger = new Trigger();
alternateRowTrigger.Property = DataGridRow.AlternationIndexProperty;
alternateRowTrigger.Value = 1;

Setter alternateRowSetter = new Setter(DataGridRow.BackgroundProperty, Brushes.Pink);
alternateRowTrigger.Setters.Add(alternateRowSetter);

DataTrigger rowDataTrigger = new DataTrigger();
rowDataTrigger.Value = true;
rowDataTrigger.Binding = new Binding() { Path = new PropertyPath(nameof(MyObject.IsSomethingTrue))};

Setter backgroundSetter = new Setter(DataGridRow.BackgroundProperty, Brushes.Blue);
Setter foregroundSetter = new Setter(DataGridRow.ForegroundProperty, Brushes.White);
rowDataTrigger.Setters.Add(backgroundSetter);
rowDataTrigger.Setters.Add(foregroundSetter);

// the order of the triggers may not be changed as explained by CptCoathanger
rowStyle.Triggers.Add(rowTrigger);
rowStyle.Triggers.Add(alternateRowTrigger);
rowStyle.Triggers.Add(rowDataTrigger);            

RootDataGridOrders.RowStyle = rowStyle;
```